# mcq the value of the following integral $ \int_{0}^{1}te^{-t^{2}}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration

the value of the following integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}te^{-t^{2}}dt $ is :

1. $\dfrac{1}{e} $
2. $\dfrac{1}{2e} $
3. $\dfrac{e-1}{2e} $

Let

- $u(t)=t$ then $u'(t)=1$
- $v'(t)=e^{-t^{2}}$ then $v(t)=\dfrac{e^{-t^{2}}}{-2t} $

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}te^{-t^{2}}dt=\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{2}\bigg|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{e^{-t^{2}}}{-2t}dt=  $$

Comment: You don't have to use parts, a u-substitution will work. Let $u = -t^2$ then $du = -2t dt$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: You have been given a hint as to a solution via 'inspection' - which is the most efficent way of comuting this integral. In any case if $$v'(t)=e^{-t^{2}} \not \implies v(t) = \frac{e^{-t^{2}}}{-2t}+C$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \int_{0}^{1} te^{-t^2}dt$$

$$u=-t^2$$

$$du=-2tdt$$

$$t=0,u=0$$
$$t=1u=-1$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} te^{-t^2}dt=\int_{0}^{-1} -\frac{1}{2}e^udu$$

$$-\frac{1}{2}[e^u]_0^{-1}=-\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{e}-1] $$

$$ \frac{e-1}{2e}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : what is the derivative of $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of per partes, try a simple substitution. Remember, the derivative of $t^2$ is $2t$, and in your function, both $t^2$ and $t$ appear.